# 'NameError' for not defined variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to run a script.
Here is what I have in the script:
`art = __import__(f'arts.{artFile}', globals(), locals(), ['*'])` 
I have a folder arts with a file named art.py.
When I try to run the script I received the following error:
`art = __import__(f'arts.{artFile}', globals(), locals(), ['*']) NameError: name 'artFile' is not defined`.
Can somebody please help?

Comment: Where do you define `artFile` variable? Please post all relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

the f before `f'arts.{artFile}'` denotes a format string, which inserts the variable `artfile` into the string.
So your script should look something like this

```
artFile = "Filename"
art = __import__(f'arts.{artFile}', globals(), locals(), ['*'])
```

```
artFile = "Filename"
print(f'arts.{artFile}')
```

should print something like

```
arts.Filename
```

with the script you shared the solution is to fix the entry in the config file, which should be in the same directory.
to fix your problem use make `artFile="art"` in the file config.py.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking at this script:
https://github.com/hemantapkh/PyBirthdayWish/blob/main/PyBirthdayWish.py

Comment: we now need your config file as well, since that defines the file to import

Comment: https://github.com/hemantapkh/PyBirthdayWish/blob/main/config.py Here it is.

Comment: the config file on github works fine, the one you use is broken.

Comment: I am using the same config file as the one in github.

Comment: try downloading or cloning the folder again, it works on both ubuntu and windows  for me.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
os.chdir(fullpath_of_arts_folder)
x = __import__(filename)
```

just use os to change the current path and access the file. :D